# Can HDF5 tables be used by different versions of pandas than what they were created on?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have a pandas dataframe stored in a `.h5` file. I wanted to work on the data on my home machine, so I copied it onto my laptop. To my surprise, I was unable to load the dataframe, though the table loaded without incident. Moreover, when I printed the `.h5` file on the machine it was made on (with pandas 0.13.0), I got the following result:

```
File path: wavefunction_file_key_2000.wfn.npy.h5
/wavefunction            frame        (shape->[1478,10001])
```

But on the other machine (pandas 0.7.0), it was:

```
File path: wavefunction_file_key_2000.wfn.npy.h5
wavefunction     DataFrame
```

Is the shape information lost when the file is copied between computers? Or are different versions of HDF5 incompatible?

Comment: it looks like the bottom version is using a much older version of pandas; the hdf files are compatible when using pandas versions >= 0.10.1 (a new version of pandas should be able to read an older version, but an older version may not be able to read a newer version)

Comment: @Jeff: You might want to write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should be compatible even across platforms / HDF versions.

You should be able to read even a very old version with a pandas versions >= 0.10.1 (when the newer format stabilized)

However it is not possible to read a newer version (your top print) with a pre-0.10.1 version of pandas (the bottom print).